# How to develop Knowledge center in WordPress Website

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, custom-taxonomy, hierarchical

I need to develop Knowledge Center Concept in my Website, where I can Publish Blog Posts, Case Studies, Customer Success Stories, Info-graphics & Whitepapers etc.

How can i develop such concept in WordPress Website.?

Like I know the Concept of Custom Post Types for Case Studies which I had already made in my current website but now I bit confused about post categorization and filter.

For Example in WordPress there are few formats are available in post format like Standard, Aside, Audio, Chat, Gallery, Image, Link etc. so could or I need to add custom support for few more formats, or to category to each post like case-studies, Info-graphics or whitepaper and play around, or

should I go for custom post types for each category like cpt for case study and then play around for custom loops.

Please help for standard practice and best way to develop such kind of concept.

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about custom post types or post formats, at least not to start with. Just add all your content as posts assigned to categories. Keep it simple.

Comment: so apart from case study, will add remain post align with categories system because had already added more then 250 case studies in website so can not re-add that all.. ;)